# Overriding a protected variable in a dervied class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have the following project, in which I define a main class called frame, and from that class I derive multiple type of classes. The main class "frame" has a protected variable defined as:

```
class frame {
protected:
    char header[4];
}
```

And in the derived classes I want the array header to have different size, as the following:

```
class dervied_frame : public frame {
protected:
    char header[8];
}
```

So my question is it possible to override the protected variable in the derived classes? and how to do that?

**Note:** I don't want to define the header as a pointer and in then in the constructor I define the size that I want through dynamic allocation.

Comment: its simple, dont use protected variables (most of the time there's a better ideia to your implementation)

Comment: No, because the "header" has a fixed size. You can easily do this with dynamic allocation. Why is that not a valid option?

Comment: @Tietbohl He wants to override the variable, not hide it.

Comment: @Tietbohl so what should I use?

Comment: @HA-AS dynamic allocation or what IronMensan mentioned, but read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3933120/2709465

Comment: well the simplest would be to use `std:vector<char>` instead of char[].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a template like this:

```
template <int headerSize>
class frame {
protected:
    char header[headerSize];
};

class dervied_frame : public frame<8> {
};
```

But then every sub-class will have a unique base class so you won't really be able to do anything with a `frame *`.  Depending on what you are using this class for, that restriction could be a deal breaker.  You can partially get around this by adding another super-class:

```
class frame {
public:
    void otherMethodsHere();
};

template <int headerSize>
class frameHeader : public frame {
protected:
    char header[headerSize];
};

class dervied_frame : public frameHeader<8> {
};
```

Comment: @HA-AS The caveat for the templated base class is an important one.